# Issue Subject : Not able to get online meeting ID of other users using Admin User Credentials

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

i am facing weird issue where i am trying to get online meeting details of user Rahul using access token of user prathamesh. user prathamesh is global admin and
using "Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy" permission is given to same user. when i am trying to fetch meeting details of Rahul using joinweburl below

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/prathamesh user id from azure/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'meeting url of Rahul'

i am getting below error.

{
"error": {
"code": "",
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The requested resource is not a collection. Query options $filter, $orderby, $count, $skip, and $top can be applied only
on collections.",
"innerError": {
"message": "The requested resource is not a collection. Query options $filter, $orderby, $count, $skip, and $top can be applied only on collections.",
"date": "2021-06-28T19:10:11",
"request-id": "b4cdd933-88a6-4784-99b3-93bb776501a4",
"client-request-id": "b4cdd933-88a6-4784-99b3-93bb776501a4"
}
}
}

can anyone please help me in this issue

Comment: Can you share the exact URL that you're trying when you got the above error? Also specify what's the parameters that you used as part of the above powershell cmdlet as well.

Comment: Is this request working fine when you try to fetch onlineMeeting of prathamesh instead?